# Symfony2/Doctrine count related to related

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm not sure if this is possible:

I have deep relations between several entities, and I don't know how to efficiently count the related entities, to show the cumulative totals for each one.

- I have a "Magazine".
- A "Magazine" have several "Issues".
- An "Issue" have several "Chapters".
- A "Chapter" have several "Pages".
- And so on...

I want to display something like:

```
Magazine A: 6 issues, 12 chapters, 24 pages
Magazine B: 12 issues, 20 chapters, 51 pages
```

So, when retrieving a "Magazine":

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Magazine')->findBy(array(),
    array('name' => 'ASC'));
```

In the template I can do this:

```
<td>{{ entity.issues.count }}</td>
```

To show the number of "Issues" related to that "Magazine".

My problem is that now I want the cumulative number of "Chapters" that these subset of "Issues" have, and so on. Something like:

```
<td class="counter">{{ entity.issues.chapters.count }}</td>
<td class="counter">{{ entity.issues.chapters.pages.count }}</td>
```

Obviously this doesn't work, and I can't figure out a way to do this. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
{{ entity.issues|length }}
```

Comment: No, the first part works fine. With {{ entity.issues.count }} I can obtain that "6 issues", what I can't have is the {{ entity.issues.chapters.count }}, since {{entity.issues}} doesn't hold, I think, the count of chapters.

Comment: lokk at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454839/symfony2-twig-get-total-count-for-child-entity

Answer (score 0):

`{{ entity.issues.chapters.pages.count }}` won't work, because `entity.issues` is an Array Collection. You can get a chapters of issue like this:

```
{{ entity.issues[INDEX_KEY].chapters.pages.count }}
```

or

```
{% for issue in entity.issues %}
    {{ issue.chapters.count }}
{% endfor %}
```